# Link Schema to Hive and HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

I'm just learning about Hadoop environment. My current task is to link schema from Hive to HDFS but I'm unsure if it is done correctly and properly.
[image]

Comment: That log line seems to be before the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`, so I would ignore it. Use `DESCRIBE TABLE` to see the schema after it's created